# How to remove property before submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a `form` field before submitting so it will not go throw the http request but still be available to the user.
This is my form submitting function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: vm.basePath + vm.configProprs.apiEndPoint.formPath,
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#p2pForm').serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    $log.log(response);
    vm.processResponse(response, vm.details);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    $timeout(function() {
      vm.isFormInvalid = true;
    }, 10);
  }
});
```

And the element I want to remove from the form data:

```
<input type="number" name ="m_accountNumber" id="m_accountNumber"  required/>
```

I have tried `.remove()` and some other jQuery functions but could not find one that remove the property from the the request.

Comment: If the field is not required to be handled by the server, just remove the name property from the input element.

Comment: @OleHaugset I think removing name filed also will affected required field validation too

Comment: Yes it will affect the validation, but not a bas way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore field while `serialize` the form:

```
var serializeData = $('input[name!=m_accountNumber]', $('#p2pForm')).serialize();
```

For multiple add class to every element which you need ignore and use `not` selector:

```
var serializeData = $('#p2pForm').not(".ignore").serialize()
```

Comment: and lets say I want to add several fields, what is the syntax?